# Rails - Test RabbitMQ notifications with Rspec. I am using the bunny gem

Tags: testing, ruby-on-rails-4, rabbitmq, bunny

I am working on a very small app, it is a RabbitMQ notification system. It triggers an API call when a state changes. That part is fine and I believe is working correctly. What I am having problems is testing the notification part, I am using rspec and I do not have  a way to test the notification, or do not know of a way. I have heard of mocking the RabbitMQ call in the test, but I do not know what that means specifically. Can anybody explain? thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For testing app working with rabbitmq you can try [evented-spec](https://github.com/ruby-amqp/evented-spec) or [moqueue](https://github.com/danielsdeleo/moqueue).
For example, stubbing connect to *AMQP* (in moqueue):

```
before(:each) do
  reset_broker
  producer.stub(:connect).and_return(mock_exchange(:topic => "common"))
end
```

Other examples you can see [here](https://github.com/danielsdeleo/moqueue/blob/master/spec/examples/basic_usage_spec.rb)